# jquery image validation not working for array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-validate

jQuery validation is working fine but it's not working for array. Please check the working code in here.

http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/1050/

If I added array in input then it's not working.

html code

```
<form id="createprofile">
  <input type="file" name="profilepic[]">
  <input type="file" name="profilepic[]">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery code

```
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
}, 'File size must be less than {0}');
jQuery(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $('#createprofile').validate({
        errorElement: "label"
        , errorClass: "has-error"
        , submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit(); //return false;
        }
        , highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('success').addClass('has-error');
        }
        , rules: {
            profilepic[]: { 
                extension: "jpg,jpeg"
                , filesize: 300000, //500kb
            } 
        },
        messages: {
            profilepic[]: { 
                extension: "Please upload only jpg, jpeg format"
                ,filesize: "Please upload maximum 500Kb"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: why you're trying to use [] in name attribute?

Comment: @AminurRashid because there are multiple inputs for same name. User can upload multiple images.

Comment: AFAIK, name attribute only contains string value, it doesn't matter if you use array notation([]) in name.

Comment: @AminurRashid what will be the solution then. Still I didnt fix this issue :(

Comment: are you using this name anywhere else in your code? if not, then you can remove this attribute.

Comment: Im using in the system thatswhy I need it. There are multiple inputs with same name.

Comment: With this plugin, you cannot have multiple inputs sharing the same `name`.  See how the code in the accepted answer will fail:  http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/1056/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add "profilepicp[]"

working code http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/1052/

```
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function (value, element, param) {
return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)}, 'File size must be less than {0}');
jQuery(function ($) {
"use strict";
$('#createprofile').validate({
    errorElement: "label"
    , errorClass: "has-error"
    , submitHandler: function (form) {
        form.submit(); //return false;
    }
    , highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('success').addClass('has-error');
    }
    , rules: {
        "profilepic[]": { 
            extension: "jpg,jpeg"
            , filesize: 300000, //500kb
        }
        , profileurl: {
            remote: {
                url: "http://localhost:8888/codeigniternew/edit/username_exists"
                , type: "post"
            }
        }
        , email: {
            required: true
            , remote: {
                url: "http://localhost:8888/codeigniternew/edit/email_exists"
                , type: "post"
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "profilepic[]": { 
            extension: "Please upload only jpg, jpeg format"
            ,filesize: "Please upload maximum 500Kb"
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Completely fails when using the OP's markup.  With this plugin, you cannot have multiple inputs sharing the same `name`.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/1056/

Comment: @Sparky yes you're right. When multiple inputs there it shows the error message to first input. It should be fix. Can you help me to fix the error. Please

Comment: @user7152572, it cannot be "fixed" and this answer should never have been accepted. **Every text input must have a unique `name`; there are no workarounds.**

Comment: @Sparky yes ur right. It should be unique name. You can use numbers inside the array. Check this demo. http://jsfiddle.net/ThE5K/6/

Answer (score -1):

html code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<form id="FORM_SEND_IMAGE">
  <input type="file" id="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

jquery code

```
function getExtension(filename) {
    var parts = filename.split('.');
    return parts[parts.length - 1];
}

function isImage(filename) {
    var ext = getExtension(filename);
    switch (ext.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'jpg':
    case 'png':
    case 'gif':
        //etc
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).on('submit', '#FORM_SEND_IMAGE', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    function failValidation(msg) {
        alert(msg); // just an alert for now but you can spice this up later
        return false;
    }

    var file = $('#file');
    if (!isImage(file.val())) {
        return failValidation('Please select a valid image');
    }

    var form_data = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'gallery/add',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log('before');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log('complete');
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    });
});
```

[demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyybzpvd/1/)

Comment: please read my question properly. my code is working fine I want to make input array, then its not working.

Comment: multiple images @user7152572 ?

Comment: yes It should work for multiple inputs with same name. Please help me to fix